# Add/remove class name in react obj?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-bootstrap

How to add/remove class without knowing the base class components ?

```
<Img variant="top" className={isImageOn ?  '': 'd-none'} src={dp} />
```

I just want to add/remove `d-none` class to the `<Img/>` object based on the bool var. In this example here it is setting the class to null if `isImageOn` is true. Can someone help on this please ?

Comment: What you have should be syntactically correct, other than a typo where `class` should be `className`. Fix that and recheck running your code as it's unclear what you are really having an issue with.

Comment: Yes that is a typo. But that is not the issue.  How to add or remove a single className from preset className ? I am using react bootstrap and want to add or remove visibility based on condition.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] so we've more context?

Answer (score 0):

The component `Img` has to provide a way to allow customization of the classes of the element that will be rendered. (You cannot add/remove class in an absolue generic way/without knowing the interface of the component you are using)

A basic way Img can allow customization:

```
const Img = ({ className, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <img {...props} className={`... ${className || ''}`} />
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If its react jsx it should work, just change class for className

```
<Img variant="top" className={isImageOn ?  '': 'd-none'} src={dp} />
```